# Jquery Array Value Loading Issue

Tags: jquery

I created an array and loaded it to html page but it only loads partial of my array (stops at 9/29/2015). I have no clue why it does not load all data? Below is my code:
    clsstartdate.js code:

```
(function(){
    window.onload= function addList(){   
     var currentDt = new Date();      
     var mm = currentDt.getMonth() + 1;
    //if(mm <= 9) mm = '0'+mm;
    var dd = currentDt.getDate();
    //if(dd<= 9) dd = '0'+dd;
    var yyyy = currentDt.getFullYear();
    var date = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

    var select = document.getElementById("zstartdate"); 
var options = ["8/24/2015","8/25/2015","8/27/2015","8/28/2015","8/29/2015","8/31/2015","9/1/2015","9/2/2015","9/3/2015","9/5/2015","9/7/2015","9/8/2015","9/9/2015","9/10/2015","9/12/2015","9/13/2015","9/14/2015","9/15/2015","9/16/2015","9/17/2015","9/18/2015","9/19/2015","9/21/2015","9/23/2015","9/24/2015","9/25/2015","9/26/2015","9/28/2015","9/29/2015","10/2/2015","10/5/2015","10/16/2015","10/17/2015","10/18/2015","10/19/2015","10/21/2015","10/22/2015","10/23/2015","10/26/2015","10/27/2015","10/28/2015","11/7/2015","11/11/2015","11/13/2015","11/14/2015","11/16/2015","11/18/2015","11/19/2015","11/21/2015","11/23/2015","11/29/2015"]; 

        for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) 
        {
            var opt = options[i];

            if (opt > date)
            {
             var option = document.createElement('option');
             option.text = option.value =opt;

            select.add(option, 0);
            }

        }
    }
    })();
```

Below is html page code:

```
<html>
<head>       
<script src="clsstartdate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       
</head>
<body>     
<form action="schedule.html" id="form" method="get" name="form">
Start Date:
<select id="zstartdate" name="zstartdate">
<option value="-1">Select</option>
</select>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search"/></form>     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a string comparison when you really want to be using date comparison.

You can compare two date objects directly using comparison operators so you can get rid of the date parsing to string from `cuurentDt` and do the following

```
    var currentDt = new Date();

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      var opt = options[i];
      // create date object from array value and compare to  currentDt
      if (new Date(opt) > currentDt) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = option.value = opt;

        select.add(option, 0);
      }

    }
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/KjsVU3yU27FdEoARVsgF?p=preview)</kbd>